# facebook login - Invalid hash key - why is it references a hash key that is not in my code?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am following the instructions for integrating facebook login into my android app using the information on this page.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started

After writing the code, when I click on "log in with facebook" I am greeted with an error on the facebook page.  The error states

> invalid key hash. The key hash [ZmdB....] does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at developers.facebook.com/apps/[appID]

the key hash [ZmdB...] does not exist anywhere in my code so I don't know why it is appearing in the error.

I did generate the key hash for the app using the instructions on facebook's site, only I did customize it my environment (generic version shown here): keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

I took the resulting key hash and added it on the facebook developer site under my platform [Android] and key hashes.  The key hash that appears there is not the same key hash reported as an error by facebook it is an entirely different value.

I have searched my code for the value that facebook reports as being an error, but cannot find it in my code, nor on the facebook developer site.

I can't figure out what I should do as a next step, seeing how I cannot identify where this erroneous hash is coming from.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the key hash [ZmdB...] does not exist anywhere in my code so I don't know why it is appearing in the error

It is the unique string that identifies your app in your development environment. Its not present in your source code.

You dont need to generare the keyhash from command line. If you read further down on the link there is a code to print the key hash:

```
// Add code to print out the key hash
try {
    PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
            "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", //your unique package name here
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
        Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));// this line  gives your keyhash
        }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

}
```

Alternately facebook native app will show key-hash along with the error. You could type that too.

Comment: Hi illegal argument - I tried to just put the hash that was reported by facebook into the hash key area of my app on the facebook developer site.  It won't accept it.  usually it makes the hash that I enter into a grey box with an "X" to erase it, but when I enter the hash that facebook reported, it does not.  When I try to "save" my changes with the facebook hash, I am getting an error that a hash is required...

Comment: @user198923 Try the above code it worked for my app and I am sure it will for you too

Comment: Thank you! Generating the hash with this code was perfect

Answer (score 0):

It's work,use the command line:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias your-alias -keystore your-keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```